# using Inheritance with generics

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, interface

suppose that i have a base class

```
class Document
{
//some properties
}
```

and
two derived classes:

```
public class Order:Document
    {
    //some properties   
    }
public class Request:Document
{
    //some properties   
}
```

now i want make a layered application that have a service layer. also i want have a base service layer interface such as:

```
public interface IBaseService<T> where T:Document
{
    IList<T> GetAll();
}
```

that my layer service classes implement it:

```
public SaleService:IBaseService<Document>;
```

So i must define `IList<Document> GetAll()` to implement base service, but i want my SaleService has `IList<Order> GetAll()` and `IList<Request> GetAll()` methods, instead `IList<Document> GetAll()`.
how can i do it?

Comment: You can't because you set one `IList<T>` method in `IBaseService<T>` interface.

Comment: It sounds like you have to have two different `GetAll()` methods on the same class, with different return types.  You can't do that in C#.  Please try to clarify your question.

Comment: yeah i have two different GetAll() methods on same class with different return types.

Comment: You should simply use `public SaleService:IBaseService<Order> ...;` , otherwise the `<T>` parameter is superfluous.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to implement `IBaseService<T>` explicitly with the different generic parameters:

```
public class SalesService : IBaseService<Order>, IBaseService<Request>
{
    IList<Order> IBaseService<Order>.GetAll()
    {
        //return orders
    }

    IList<Request> IBaseService<Request>.GetAll()
    {
        //return requests
    }
}
```

The implemented methods are only visible through the interface, so you'll have to cast to call them e.g.

```
IBaseService<Request> service = new SalesService();
IList<Request> request = service.GetAll();
```

Your client code should only depend on the `IBaseService<T>` interface, so you shouldn't need to do this very often.

Comment: but by implementing explicitly `IBaseService<Order>` and `IBaseService<Request>`, modifier of GetAll methods are private and i couldn't use them on my client side code. and if change modifiers of GetAlls to public, i get this error:"The modifier 'public' is not valid for this item"

Comment: @Masoud - Yes, they're only visible through the interface so you'll need to cast - see the update. You can implement one of the `IBaseService<T>` interfaces implicitly if you want to call `GetAll` on the `SalesService` class directly.

Comment: thanks, i tested it, it worked. also it worked with `IBaseService<Request> service = new SalesService();` but another question, how can i declare `IList<Document>` instead `IList<Request>` in last line of code?